# How to find two close events (that have a datetime component) in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have an object that represents an event, and I have many types of those objects.

I want to find events that are close in time in python.

The nicest way I could find to do it is:

```
joined_events = [[event_a.time, event_a.description, event_b.time, event_b.description] for event_a in events_a for event_b in events_b if abs(event_a.time - event_b.time) < datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)]
```

But I hoped there was a better method of doing it.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a more efficient way to compare all items in two lists?

Comment: I want to know if there is a nicer way to do it, this is an ugly piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better solution so I wrote one:

https://github.com/tomirendo/Grouper

Its main purpose is to group object by their relation and replace the itertools.groupby function.

```
import datetime,random,Grouper
groups_of_dates = Grouper.groupby(list_of_dates,relation= Grouper.time_delta(hours = 3),as_iterable=False)
#Get a list of lists, grouping 
#consecutive events that are less than 3 hours apart.
```

To solve the problem I had, You can do this:

```
results = [[a,b] 
         for a,b in itertools.product(events_a ,events_b)
         if Grouper.time_delta(attr="time",hours = 3)(a,b)]
```

For a more general solution, you can use the AND,OR and difference methods:

```
groups_of_dates = Grouper.groupby(list_of_dates,
                    relation= Grouper.AND(Grouper.time_delta(hours = 3),
                               Grouper.difference(3,attr="loc")),
                    as_iterable=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but hopefully the is a little less ugly to you :)

```
import datetime
from itertools import product

delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
joined_events = [
    [a.time, a.description, b.time, b.description]
    for a, b in product(events_a, events_b) if abs(a.time - b.time) < delta
]
```